# bottle template: how to import a python package

Tags: python, bottle

I'm writing a bottle SimpleTemplate and I want to compare a date. How (and where) do you import python package inside a template? Is it possible?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. I want to compare data (a string) representing a date to today's date:

```
%if datetime.strptime(report['date'], '%m/%d/%Y') &lt; datetime.today():
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
%elif report['result']:
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"></span>
%elif not report['result']:
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>
%end
```

To make that work in a normal python program, I'd have to say

```
from datetime import datetime
```

But is there a way to do that in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Templates are not meant to include complex logic, they are part of the presentational layer. You should prepare all your data in the view and pass it on to the template already processed.

So in your case you should probably move your logic to the view - resulting in something along those lines:

```
from datetime import datetime
if datetime.strptime(report['date'], '%m/%d/%Y') > datetime.today():
    report["status"] = "due"
else:
    if report["result"]:
        report["status"] = "pending_check"
    else:
        report["status"] = "missing_result"
```

and then in the template check the flag, like so:

```
%if report["status"] == "due":
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
%elif report["status"] == "pending_check":
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"></span>
%elif report["status"] == "missing_result":
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>
%end
```

I have not used `close`, `check` and `alert` as `report["status"]` values on purpose, because best practice would be to decouple data from presentation and therefore not assign HTML class names in the view, but rather act on the processed data in the template like I did in the attached snippet.

Then if you decide to change the icons, you do that only in your template which is superior to doing presentational changes in the view (and e.g. having to restart your web server for them to take effect).

**UPDATE (April 2016):**
Apparently it's now possible or became possible, since I answered, to import modules in Bottle templates, but it's still a bad idea :)

Comment: very good--thanks. I really should have known better, but I was only thinking of how the data exists in the db, not considering how I can manipulate that in the view.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. And don't worry, sometimes it's just hardest to figure out the simplest thing... :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, importing modules from inside templates **is** possible. This is for instance used by bottlepy itself to generate the error pages:

```
ERROR_PAGE_TEMPLATE = """
%%try:
    %%from %s import DEBUG, HTTP_CODES, request, touni
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: {{e.status}}</title>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

i just tried:

```
%from mymodule import *
```

and it seemed to work, no time to check further, i think importing is just calling a python method and therfore should work.